# pyQt and styles, listview widget highlighting first checkboxes

Tags: pyqt4, stylesheet, qlistview

I have a pyQt4 application, which uses "themes".  By "theme", I mean that there are user-selectable variants of the style.qss stylesheet, with accompanying png for specialized graphics when necessary.

I have recently used a QtListView with a QStandardItemModel, where the components of the item model were set to have a check state:

```
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem( app )
                item.setCheckState( False )
                item.setCheckable( True )
                self.model_apps.appendRow( item )

                [snip -- elsewhere in the code:]

                self.app_listview = QtGui.QListView()
                self.app_listview.setModel( self.model_apps )
```

I noticed that, in one of my themes, the first three items in the listview have a white outline around the checkbox square, but only the first three.  Not that the checkbox is selected or anything, but just that the rectangle for the checkbox seems to be drawn with a white outline around it.  In another theme, it's the first four items in the listview that are drawn this way.  In yet another theme, there is no unexpected highlighting of any of the checkboxes.  I think it's a property of the listview/model combination because I used the same kind of combination in two places for two different kinds of data and they are both showing this effect in the same way (but they are on the same parent widget).

In the "native" theme, when I set the style sheet to "", there is no unexpected highlighting of any checkboxes (on Fedora 19).

It feels like it could be related to hovering, but when I hover over any one of the checkboxes in any of the themes, they highlight in yet another color.  I don't know where to start debugging this highlighting effect which affects the first few elements of the listview in only some of the themes.  There is nothing in the themes, as far as I can tell, which specify conditional drawing instructions for listviews or checkboxes.  I assume this is a known feature that I've never heard of - what is it called (so I can figure out how to debug it)?  Thanks.

Edit: Here is an example.  Unfortunately, in this example, I'm not seeing the first elements' checkboxes outlined in white, but the 3rd-6th.

```
#!/bin/env python
try :
    import urllib.request as urllib_request # python 3.0 ready
except:
    import urllib2 as urllib_request # python 2.x compatible
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication( sys.argv )
stylesheet = urllib_request.urlopen( "http://www.yasinuludag.com/darkorange.stylesheet").read()
app.setStyleSheet( stylesheet )
main_window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
for i in range(10):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem( 'thing_%03d' % i )
    item.setCheckState( False )
    item.setCheckable( True )
    model.appendRow( item )
view = QtGui.QListView()
view.setModel(model)
main_window.setCentralWidget(view)
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a small, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem when running your example. This is probably because stylesheets override the current style, and so the exact results can be unpredictable (you're probably on a different platform, or using a different style, to me). You will have to try to narrow down the source of the problem by trial and error. Just comment out chunks of the stylesheet until the problem goes away, and then gradually add smaller parts back until it reappears. It shouldn't be too difficult to identify the specific rules that are responsible.